# Android Studio "Find usages" found results in generated sources. How to disable it?

Tags: android, android-studio

It's really annoying that Android Studio try to find `name/expression` in generated sources.

Look at screenshot below:
[image]

Does anybody know how to disable "Find usages" for specific directory eg. "build", "genarated" etc?

Answer (score 2):

I've had a similar problem when Android studio gave me results of usage from the API.

Once you performed a "find usage", open the find settings.

[image: Find screen]

Then, edit the scope from the drop-down list:

[image: Find usage settings screen]

If the available scopes do not meet your needs, you can create custom scopes via File > Settings > Appearance & Behavior > Scopes.